# Multi-client architecture advice for RavenDB

Tags: wcf, ravendb, soa

When catering for multiple .NET Client Applications - say - Web, Desktop and then throw in an Android app (Java), placing the business logic behind some WCF REST API services can make it easier and quicker to build applications, as there is no business logic to implement client side for each technology.

(I know that there will be a point of changing the UI to cater for new business logic, but the idea is the core of the system sits behind an API, not in the client application.)

Although RavenDB serves as the Storage Mechanism...

> What is the general architectural advice of using RavenDB behind SOA services? Is it just your standard `IDocumentStore`/`IDocumentSession` behind the WCF instance and go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just use it like that.
Note that RavenDB comes with clients for both .NET and Java.